# How do I use ruby get JSON back from Instagram API

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, instagram

I am doing my best to get JSON back from the instagram API. Here is the code I am trying in my rake task within rails.

```
require 'net/http'


url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/snow/media/recent?access_token=522219.f59def8.95be7b2656ec42c08bff8a159a43d06f"
resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))
puts resp.body
```

All I end up with in the terminal is "rake aborted!
end of file reached"

If you look at the instagram docs http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/ and you paste the following URL in your browser you will get JSON back so I'm sure I am doing something wrong.

https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/snow/media/recent?access_token=522219.f59def8.95be7b2656ec42c08bff8a159a43d06f

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to do with HTTPS url you need to modify your code to include SSL

```
require "net/https"
require "uri"

uri = URI.parse("https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/snow/media/recent?access_token=522219.f59def8.95be7b2656ec42c08bff8a159a43d06f")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)

response = http.request(request)
puts response.body
```

alternatively you could use somthing like https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty  to consume 3rd party services

Comment: spot on. OP may also consider using [the official ruby gem](https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem/) to consume the Instagram API.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you'd need to configure net/http to use SSL because you're using https.

Alternative : use this with Rails, it'll parse the json on the fly too :

`ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(open(URI.encode(url)))`

Returns a hash to play with